# How to properly mock Hibernate Session get(Class<T> entityType, Serializable id)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, mockito

I'm unit testing my Hibernate DAO layer with jUnit4 and Mockito and I'm having problems mocking `get(Class<T> entityType, Serializable id)`.

I have no errors along the way, the only thing is that my assertion fails as `actualAddress` is `null`.

```
// imports here
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class AddressDAOImplTest {

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private AddressDAO addressDAO;

    @Mock
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Mock
    private Session session;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getAddress() {
        Address expectedAddress = getTestAddress(1);
        Mockito
                .doReturn(session)
                .when(sessionFactory)
                .openSession();
        Mockito
                .doReturn(expectedAddress)
                .when(session)
                .get(Matchers.eq(Address.class), Matchers.anyInt()); // doesn't match
        Mockito
                .doNothing()
                .when(session)
                .close();

        Address actualAddress = addressDAO.getAddress(1);

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedAddress, actualAddress);
    }
}
```

somewhere AddressDAOImpl:

```
public Address getAddress(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Address address = null;
        try {
            address = session.get(Address.class, id); // returns null as it can't match the mocked method
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // some logging here :)
        } finally {
            session.close();
            return address;
        }
    }
```

SessionFactory setup:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.webservices.models"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Hibernate props:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:orders;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
jdbc.username=
jdbc.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

To my understanding `get(Matchers.eq(Address.class), Matchers.anyInt())` doesn't match the actual method, which leads to `null` as a return value.

I'd greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: try `Matchers.any(Address.class)`

Comment: @Deadpool when I do so my IDE is complaining `Cannot resolve method 'get(T, int)'`. I need to explicitly pass it a class type as its first parameter.

Comment: just say `Matchers.any()`

Comment: @Deadpool I don't need `any()`, I want to be precise on this one :)

Comment: i would say just try and make it work then you can go precise approach

Comment: @Deadpool I agree, but the problem with `any()` is that `session.get()` has multiple implementations, that's why I need to give it a class type and int specifically.

Comment: Try `Matchers.any(Integer.class)` instead of `Matchers.anyInt()`. The latter returns a primitive `int` whereas your primary key is an `Integer`. Autoboxing for the method argument probably doesn't apply and `int.class != Integer.class`. Also you might want to question your test, when you start mocking low-level infrastructure code like this you might want to write an integration test or use an embedded DB or TestContainers setup instead. So that you can test this as part of a broader test.